# Encoding issues lead to 2 folders created with same name in the same location

Tags: php, ios, encoding

I believe encoding issues are resulting in the creation of folders with the same same in the same location.

The first folder is created directly from the browser using a php backend.
The second is also created using the same php backend however the request comes from an IOS app.

The logic is rather simple, I send to the server a folder name to create, if the folder doesn't exist then he creates it and put a file inside otherwise he just put a file inside the existing folder.

A strange finding, is if I send a request using PostMan on Windows, the existing folder is detected and the file put inside without issue, however if I use Postman on Mac I get the same issue, where the folder is not detected as existing and created again.

Here is how I retrieve the folder name on php side:

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
```

Comment: There may be some different coding of  capital é : É character. Hitch not have been coded same way in brother and app : UTF-8 vs Other coding.

Comment: You can try to hexdump the . directory file ti compare the 2 encoding of the 2 file names

Comment: I can't figure it out, the encoding from the app is set to utf8 and phpinfo say the default charset is utf8 not sure where to look from here.

Comment: The value for É can be xC9 or xC3x89. Have you accès to php code ?

Comment: Can you check the configuration of the SFTP server ? It should force UTF-8!encoding for file names.

Comment: I have access to the php code. I tried using mb_encoding_convert, utf8 encoding, and many other options but the folder get created either with some strange characters (\311quipe Rouge, EÌ�quipe Rouge) or with the same name but duplicated. Never faced something similar before

Comment: \311 = C9 : it is octal representation

Comment: The second version is E with ‘

Comment: How do you get the team name ? That may be where you need to have a commun input in php and app.

Comment: I get from the app and I'm sur I send it as UTF8. I did a simple test hardcoding the name directly into the php string and it worked well. I also used strcmp to compare Équipe Rouge from the server with Équipe Rouge from the app (request) and Équipe Rouge != Équipe Rouge . This is insane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply [`Normalizer::normalize` -- `normalizer_normalize`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php):

```
<?php
$char__A_acute = "\xC3\x89";  // 'Latin Capital Letter E With Acute' (U+00C9)
$chars_A_acute = "\x45"       // 'Latin Capital Letter E' (U+0045)
               .  "\xCC\x81"; // 'Combining Acute Accent' (U+0301)
var_dump( $char__A_acute );
var_dump( $chars_A_acute );
var_dump( $char__A_acute == $chars_A_acute );                       
var_dump( Normalizer::normalize( $char__A_acute, Normalizer::FORM_D )
       == $chars_A_acute);                       
var_dump( $char__A_acute
       == Normalizer::normalize( $chars_A_acute, Normalizer::FORM_C ));                       
?>
```

**Output** (in fact, you can see `string(3) "E⁠´"` at the 2nd line in a simple "terminal" e.g. Windows command line `cmd`):

```
string(2) "É"
string(3) "É"
bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

In theory: [normalization forms for Unicode text](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/)

FYI, you see a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case in `EÌ�quipe Rouge` as `Ì�` is `cp1252` interpretation of utf-8 bytes of *Combining Acute Accent*.

Comment: It worked for me using the FORM_C. I don't know why do we have to use this normalizer nor how to know which form to use. Would this be universal for all accented characters if it worked for that one ? I guess so