# Cyrilic small letter short i encoded by 2 chars

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, apache2, mbstring

In php >=7.2 Russian symbol "й" (Cyrillic Small Letter Short I) encoding by 2 chars -
"и" (Cyrilic Small Letter I) + ̆ (Combining Breve). Because of this, my substring search breaks down. IN php <=7.1 all works fine. (that symbol encoded by one char). Do anyone know what the reason might be. I think that reason somewhere in config files (php, apache2, htaccess...).
PHP = 7.2.34
Apache = 2.4.29
Thank you in advance

Comment: Read about [mcve].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Encoding issues lead to 2 folders created with same name in the same location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69790463/encoding-issues-lead-to-2-folders-created-with-same-name-in-the-same-location)

Comment: Yeah, I read about Normalization, but seems this is bad way for me, because that issue I've found in everywhere on site. And I can't rewrite index.php or any other core files.

Comment: Apple prefers to use decomposed form, other prefers composed form. But it should never be a large rewrite. You should have few validation function in place, right? Right? [And you must have them on every input from users, you should just adapt for strings]